# How can I get a cookie in Angular 2, for a website?

Tags: angular

I have Angular 2 app running on http://localhost:4200 and I need to get a cookie from http://example.com/route (for simplification I leave the website names as thus). How can I do this? I can see the cookie in developer tools when I go to the site http://example.com/route, but I don't see the cookie in angular when I go to http.get("http://example.com/route"). How can I get this cookie and have it in Angular 2?

Comment: If I understood you good, you are trying to get the cookie in one domain from another domain? It is not possible by security reasons.

Comment: You can use [localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) to set and get info on client side.